# Error in rs.next() after if else?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Here is my question:
My problem is that I have `dc` as a variable, if this variable is null then else part should be executed.
But here condition is that when if() part is executed it doesn't enter into `if(rs.next())`? why ?
When my dc value is 2, `rs.next()` is working but when it is 1 its not working.

```
    if (dc != null) {
        rs = st.executeQuery("select e.env_id,s.* from env_mast e inner join"
                + " db_server_mast s on e.dc_id=s.dc_id join cust_mast c on "
                + "e.cust_id=c.cust_id where cust_name='" + env + "' and "
                + "e.dc_id='" + dc + "' ");
    } else {

        System.out.println("Not DC");
        rs = st.executeQuery("select e.env_id,s.* from env_mast e inner join "
                + "db_server_mast s on e.dc_id=s.dc_id join cust_mast c on "
                + "e.cust_id=c.cust_id where cust_name='" + env + "' ");

    }
    if (rs.next()) {
    }
```

Comment: May be it is me or your wording is very confusing. :)

Comment: May be there is no records with your matching conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding, you need to perform an `if-else` first. Then try to perform another `if-else` which do not matter that `dc = 1` or `dc = 2`

If I'm not mistaken:

```
if (rs.next())
```

will only be perform when the `dc = 2`, so in my opinion, your code should be something like this:

```
    if(dc == null) {
        System.out.println("Not DC");
        //do something when dc is null
    } else {
        System.out.println("Is DC");
        //do something when the dc is not null
        for(int i = 0; i < dc; i ++) {
            //something you perform in the if(rs.next()) { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would really recommend you use `PreapredStatement` and bind parameters (or your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks), further I would start by building the query. So, something like -

```
String sql = "select e.env_id,s.* from env_mast e inner join "
            + "db_server_mast s on e.dc_id=s.dc_id join cust_mast c on "
            + "e.cust_id=c.cust_id where cust_name=?"
            + ((dc != null) ? " and e.dc_id=?" : "");
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);) {
  ps.setString(1, env);
  if (dc != null) {
    ps.setString(2, dc);
  }
  try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
    while (rs.next()) {
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Appreciate for your PreparedStatement recommendation +1

Comment: I agree PreparedStatement concept. But it's kind of diverting the issue into something else (like Performance). He didn't ask anything related to performance, security. He simply asked to fix the issue, not expecting any code improvement.

Comment: @Rajacsp fixing the code doesnot mean opening window for future problems

Comment: @SparkOn, Opening and closing the Window or door is his issue. We are here to fix the MAIN issue. If he had asked any security or performance improvement, I would have agreed your statement (not Java Statement :-))

Comment: Its not fullfill my request

Comment: @user3977863 Yes. Try with resources was added in Java 7. Are you on an older version of Java?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is best to use prepared statement while using queries as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25615719/3492139) by Elliot.
If you still want to use statements, then you better change the approach as below to avoid confusion and for better code maintenance.

```
String selectQuery = "select e.env_id,s.* from env_mast e inner join"
                + " db_server_mast s on e.dc_id=s.dc_id join cust_mast c on "
                + "e.cust_id=c.cust_id where cust_name='" + env + "' ";

if (dc != null) 
{
   selectQuery  += " and "
                + "e.dc_id='" + dc + "' ";
}

rs = st.executeQuery (selectQuery);
if (rs.next())
{
  ....
}
```

For your question,

1. Probably, there is no record in the table env_mast  when `dc = 1`.
2. The table env_mast has records if `dc = 2`

Check your table data.

Comment: we should avoid using Statement

Comment: @SparkOn: I agree. I am suggesting the user, how it has to be implemented if they still want to use statements.

Comment: first thing never suggest Statement second thing never suggest Statement third thing never suggest Statement

Comment: @SparkOn, the issue is not based on Statement vs PreparedStatement. It is based on ResultSet. Don't simply divert the developer into something else.

Comment: As Nishanthi mentioned, you might not have results when dc = 1. Make sure you have data in your table. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I have a value 1 and 2 in my db, it was print in console. But when i had select 1, it was not execute if(rs.next) and when I had select 2, it was executing

Comment: @user3977863: Take the query and execute in your mysql console and check for errors.